# Verilog: How to extend the binary in a register?

Tags: verilog, iverilog

What's the format for the code to sign-extend and zero-extend the binary in a register?

i.e.

```
reg[0:0] a;        //a is 1-bit.
reg[31:0] b, c;    //b and c are 32-bits.
//some code...
```

Sign-extend `a` into 32-bits, add it to `b`, and put the result into `c`.

Zero-extend `a` into 32-bits, add it to `b`, and put the result into `c`.

Comment: `reg[0:0] a;` => `reg  a;` this is one bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to sign-extend, I will be using the method that requires the least amount of code. We will be using the Verilog **replication** and **concatenation** operations.

**Replication Format:** `{numberOfTimesToRepeat{value}}`

i.e. {20{a[0]}}

*Replicates the 0th bit in the* `a` *register 20 times.*

**Concatenation Format:** `{value1, value2}`

i.e. {a, b}

*Concatenates the binaries in register* `a` *and register* `b`.

**To Sign-extend:**

{{31{a[0]}}, a}

*Replicates the 0th bit in the* `a` *register 31 times, and concatenates that before the binary of register* `a`.

**To Zero-extend:**

{{31{zero}}, a}   //zero is a 1-bit register containing a zero bit.

*Replicates the value zero 31 times, and concatenates that before the binary of register* `a`.

Comment: To sign-extend a single-bit value, you don't need a concatenation. `{32{a}}` will suffice.

Comment: To zero-extend, you don't need replication or any reg named zero. `{31'b0, a}` will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a system verilog way:

```
logic signed a;
logic [31:0] b, c;
...

b = a;
```

in the above example `b` will become a sign-extended value of `a`.

Comment: Using this method, how would you zero-extend? Delcaring `logic unsigned a;` and `logic unsigned [31:0] b, c;`?

Comment: `signed` variables would be sign-extended. all others will be zero extended. Note that `signed` variables would change outcome of the relational operations since comparison will take the sign in account. Also the signed variable uses the upper bit to indicate the sign.